# Creating a Gif in ImageMagick with images of different sizes

Tags: c#, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to make a gif out of a list of images and the images have all different sizes. Is there a way to make the gif the size of the smallest image? Does it have any method like that?

I tried with Optimize and Coalesce but they don't do what I want. I followed this link and I couldn't find anything similar to what I need [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#frame_opt)

Here's what I do but it doesn't work:

```
using (MagickImageCollection collection = new MagickImageCollection(magickImages))
        {
            QuantizeSettings settings = new QuantizeSettings();
            settings.Colors = 256;
            collection.Quantize(settings);

            collection.Coalesce();
            collection.Optimize();
            collection.OptimizeTransparency();
            collection.Write(stream, MagickFormat.Gif);
        }
```

Comment: How would IM determine how to crop the bigger images?

Comment: I don't know, the center? So there's no functionality for this, right?

Comment: What do you mean by size? Filesize or dimensions. If the latter, then you will have to read each gif, find it dimensions and compare to the next image's dimensions and keep the dimensions of the smallest. Then use that when resizing. But I do not see any resizing or scaling in your commands. Are you asking about the file size? If so, I do not know how you would force all the gifs to that size apart from resizing them to be smaller. If you want to optimize the gifs to reduce file size, use the equivalent of -layers optimize, but you cannot force it to some particular size. Please clarify.